# Difference in meaning between "She supped up her soup" and "She supped on her soup"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between "She supped **up** her soup" and "She supped **on** her soup" ?

Does "She supped up her soup" mean "She ate the soup completely"?
Does "She supped on her soup" mean She was eating soup. The soup still remained" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both definitions are given by  [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sup)

> She supped up her soup

means she ate her soup in small sips.

> She supped on her soup

means she ate her soup for supper.

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard "sup up" used before - "sup on" means to eat for supper (or dinner, as the evening meal is more commonly known nowadays, at least in the US). Just so you know - at least in American English - the word "sup" sounds very dainty and old-fashioned. Normally you'd just say "She ate her soup" or to be more specific about what meal it was, "She ate her soup for dinner."

Comment: Good point. There's a similar word, 'sip', that means the same thing and is used frequently in American English.

Comment: I would say “sip” is used for drinks only and means “to take a small drink of”. Soup is a liquid food but I would not say someone sips soup- you can sip water, coffee, beer, etc. - anything that is served in a glass or mug or other drinking vessel.

Comment: Sounds like we use that word differently. People sometimes drink soup from a mug, and I would say somebody could sip something from a spoon. That's okay - different perspectives.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sup#h70103499105380), this is correct:

> ‘she supped **up** her soup [delightedly]’